# How to get the node name associated with the value in c#

Tags: xml, c#-4.0

```
<NodeA>
  <ChildNode>
     XYZ
  </ChildNode>
  <ChildNode1>
     ABC
  </ChildNode1>
</NodeA>
```

I have an XML.
Suppose if I get the value as ABC I want to check that which node it is coming from so the answer should be like "ChildNode1".
Can we get this type of thing ?

Comment: Sure. I'd use LINQ to XML if I were you. I suggest you try it for yourself (remember that "where" is used in LINQ queries...) and then post what you've tried and what happened if you're still stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
            string xml =
                "<NodeA>" +
                  "<ChildNode>" +
                     "XYZ" +
                  "</ChildNode>" +
                  "<ChildNode1>" +
                     "ABC" +
                  "</ChildNode1>" +
                "</NodeA>";
            XElement nodeA = XElement.Parse(xml);
            List<string> abc = nodeA.Elements().Where(x => x.Value == "ABC").Select(x => x.Value).ToList();​
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ to XML for this.

So to get the node names with a specific value you can use something like this:

```
var nodeNames = xdoc.Root.Elements()
    .Where(n => n.Value == "ABC")
    .Select(n => n.Name.ToString())
    .ToList();

nodeNames.ForEach(n => Console.WriteLine(n));
```

This would print "ChildNode1"

In the XML you posted there are some line breaks and spaces so if that's your actual XML you're working with you may need to check without the spaces like this:

```
var nodeNames = xdoc.Root.Elements()
    .Where(n => n.Value.Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r", "").Replace(" ", "") == "ABC")
    .Select(n => n.Name.ToString())
    .ToList();
```